# jQuery addClass works on jsfiddle but not live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've gone through several of the questions similar to mine, and have tried to implement their solutions, but I haven't managed to get any to work.

This is the js code I am using on my live site:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $(".icon_circle").click(function () {
        $('circle').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
   });

});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AKXTV/3 (it is adapted from [jQuery SVG removeClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439647/jquery-svg-removeclass))

Here is my live site: http://watchcampfire.com/pre

Edit: Looks like it isn't working in bootply either, so it may be an issue with it working alongside some Bootstrap coding. http://www.bootply.com/120685

Comment: You should fix error in console...

Comment: `$('circle')` isn't a DOM object, so you can't use `removeClass()` on it.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will look into the errors in the console. I'm working from a ready-made-theme, so I didn't write the code. Also @Samsquanch, is there any reason why the code would then work fine in jsfiddle if `$('circle')` is not a DOM object? Sorry, I am very new to SVG and not well-versed in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing a place where you initialize that swiper plugin like so (according to their website):

```
$(function(){
  var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
    //Your options here:
    mode:'horizontal',
    loop: true
    //etc..
  });
})
```

Because you don't seem to have that, that may be the cause of the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList'` of undefined errors. Fixing that should make things work for you.

UPDATE:

I think I figured out the root cause of the problem here.

This should work:

```
$('.icon_circle').on('click', function() {
  $('.icon_circle').attr('class', function(index, classNames) {
      //this is sort of lazy, oh well
      return 'icon_circle';
  });  

  $(this).attr('class', function(index, classNames) {
      return classNames + ' clicked';
  });
});
```

There's some sort of issue with adding/removing classes on SVG elements.

More detail here: [jQuery SVG, why can't I addClass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass)

Comment: I'm actually working from an already-made-theme. From what I can see, it is being initialized from js/scripts.js. But that may be incorrect? Though, it appears the swiper is working, but still causing errors in console.

Comment: So its an issue related to adding classes to SVG elements. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass

Comment: Wow @ccnokes! Thanks! This seems pretty close. From what I can see, the black stroke gets automatically applied, rather than only appearing after clicking on the icon. http://www.bootply.com/120696

Comment: Updated my answer above. This works for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/95ppn/ You just needed to add the new way of adding/removing a class in with the rest of your logic and the click event.

Comment: That's so awesome! Thanks! I think I just might switch back to this  to complete the action.

Answer (score 0):

On your website,lot of JS errors are coming up  which are stopping your script execution. Resolve those errors first and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to some invalid markup.

If you look at your jsFiddle, you are missing closing `</g>` tags inside of several `<svg />` tags.

You can tell because the closing `</svg>` tags will be red.

---

You also have `<g id="circle">` repeated several times.

You can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed the `<g></g>` tags and removed the circle IDs (they were created when exporting from AI) in the live site. Unfortunately, the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting a helping hand from PencilScoop.

Here's the perfect working solution that involves no JS at all.

I wrapped my SVG, like so:

```
<input type="radio" id="v" name="button" value="video">
<label for="v">
<!-- SVG CODE -->
</label>
```

Then added this to the CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label #shape_ID {
    stroke: #EF4137
}
```

See working code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3KnXF/5